# UITableViewRowAction - background colour of one affects the other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have 3 `UITableViewRowAction's` in my source code, like below:

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                  editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(messagePremission)
    {
        messageAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSLocalizedString(@"message_admin", nil), activity.GroupName] handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){

                }];

        messageAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:82.0/255.0 green:82.0/255.0 blue:82.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        messageAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSLocalizedString(@"message_admin", nil), activity.GroupName] handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){

                }];

        messageAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:199.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    }

    if(editPermission)
    {
        editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:NSLocalizedString(@"edit_swipe", nil) handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){

            }];

        editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:NSLocalizedString(@"edit_swipe", nil) handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){

            }];

        editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    }
    if(cancelPermission)
    {
        cancelAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Cancel"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){   
            }];

        cancelAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:13.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        cancelAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Cancel"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){   
            }];

        cancelAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:13.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    }  

    [arrButtons addObject:messageAction];
    [arrButtons addObject:editAction];
    [arrButtons addObject:cancelAction]; 

    return arrButtons;
}
```

In each `if` condition, a button is created as enabled, whereas in the respective `else` condition, as disabled.

However, the `backgroundColor` of `messageAction` affects the other two when only `messageAction` is enabled and other two are disabled.

To confirm this, I reversed the buttons display order by putting `cancelAction` as first. That way, cancel button's `backgroundColor` affected other two.

How can I fix the visualization od `backgroundColor` property of each button?

Comment: what's the desired behavior? it is not clear

Comment: @ddb : Desired behaviour is to show the buttons in disabled form (by lightening their background) when they don't have the permission.

Comment: @ddb : But if it would be only one object, then how do you suggest to display 3 different buttons ?

Comment: @ddb : You deleted your answer !!

Comment: Yes, it is not correct, eventally I'll write a new one ;) sorry, but I do not want to receive down-votes for nothing

Comment: (just guessing, as your code seems correct after you explained to me better) may you try to split and exec the `addObject:` statements just after each specific if-else branch?

Comment: Try to use `ternary operator` rather than if-else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Override the [`editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:) tableview delegate method as follows:-

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewRowAction *messageButton = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Message" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Action to perform with messageButton Button");
                                    }];
    UIColor *messageColor  = if(messagePremission == true) ? [UIColor colorWithRed:82.0/255.0 green:82.0/255.0 blue:82.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] :
        [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:199.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    messageButton.backgroundColor = messageColor;

    UITableViewRowAction *editButton = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Action to perform with editButton Button!");
                                     }];
    UIColor *editColor  = if(editPermission == true) ? [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] :
        [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    editButton.backgroundColor = editColor;

    UITableViewRowAction *cancelButton = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Cancel" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Action to perform with cancelButton");
                                     }];
    UIColor *cancelColor  = if(cancelPermission == true) ? [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:13.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] :
        [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:1.0/255.0 blue:13.0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = cancelColor;

    return @[messageButton, editButton, cancelButton];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background colours have alpha values - The action views are drawn overtop of each other from the rightmost button inwards.

Use a colour with no alpha and it should be fine and not blend with the other button background colours.